# MultiOutputRegressor in spark/scala for xgboost

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, xgboost

Do we have *MultiOutputRegressor* as a wrapper for *xgboost* using spark/scala in distributed way with the help of xgboost4j-spark, my requirement is to implement multiple target prediction.

Please find below the python code snippet for reference.

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn import ensemble
import xgboost as xgb

xgbr = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=1, eta=0.01, silent=1, subsample= 0.8, reg_lambda = 1.515, 
             reg_alpha= 0.0017, min_child_weight=7, colsample_bytree=0.85, nthread= 32,
             gamma= 0.01, objective='reg:linear',tree_method= 'approx', booster = 'gbtree', n_estimators=100)

X = ["indep_1","indep_2","indep3","indep_4","indep_5","indep_6","indep_7","indep_8"]
Y = ["dep_1","dep_2","dep_3","dep_4"]

model = MultiOutputRegressor(xgbr).fit(X, Y)
```